# Java learning problems arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone explain to me the answer?
What does **x** equal at the end?

```
int[] vs = {4, 15, 6, 26, 7, 8}; 
int x = vs[0]; 
for (int v : vs) 
   { 
     if (v < x) { x = v; }
   }
```

Comment: I think the result is known, the OP wants to have an explanation, which seems to be the aim of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give this another try since I find sfThomas' answer a little confusing.

So:
The answer to your question upfront: x will equal *4*. And the purpose of your little algorithm is simply to find the smallest (numerical) value in a given list of values.

**Detailed explanation:**

- In line 1 you set up an array (think of it as an ordered list of values) of integer values (aka "whole numbers"). This array is called `vs`.
- In line 2 you assign the variable `x` to the first element within `vs`. This happens to be *4*.
- Line 3 a for-each loop (official terminology in Java: "Enhanced for Loop") is declared. It executes the loop body (lines 4-6) for each element of the array `vs`. In each iteration `v` will hold the value of the currently processed element. Processing order equals declaration order. Thus: In the first iteration `v` will equal *4*, in the second *15* and so on.
  A traditional for loop to accomplish the same is given below.
- The body of your loop (line 5) consists of a check whether `v` is ever smaller than `x`. This is never the case (i.e. there is no value within your array `vs` that is smaller than the value of the first element of `vs`) and therefore the code within the brackets `x = v;` (which would reassign `x` to the value of this smaller element every time such a smaller element is found) never gets executed. In other words: `x` always stays with its initial value `vs[0]` and that is *4*.

I hope this was clear enough for a beginner.

```
for (int i=0; i<vs.length; i++) {
    int v = vs[i];
    // rest of the loop body
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks for the smallest element in your array - the last part iterates over each element, and if it finds one that is smaller than the previous value, saves that instead in variable 'x'.

`for (int v : vs)` - this executes the block that is after with each value in the vs array, in a way that variable `v` is assigned to the given value.
Have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/).

{ if (v < x) { x = v; }} - this checks if the current `v` value is smaller than `x`, and then if so, saves that value in `x`.

Comment: so when int x = vs[0] it sets x to be 4?

Comment: yes, that statement initializes x to be the first element in the array

Comment: then what does this do for (int v : vs) { if (v < x) { x = v; }}??
sorry, I'm just starting to learn programming. :)

Comment: so in this case the answer is not 4?

Comment: It is, but if you had e.g int[] vs = {4, 15, 6, 26, 7, 8, 2}, than the answer would be 2.